# Use iptables to redirect **all* requests, even DNS-unsolved domain?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, dnsmasq, iptables-redirect

> Context: With `iptables`, I redirect all the traffic - incoming at port 80 - to a distant server IP (X.X.X.X). I aim that **anywhat** you write in the urlbar of browser, you get X.X.X.X.

1. **IP** That works a charm with IP (If I request 12.2.4.5, I fallback on X.X.X.X).
2. **Resolved Domain** (In `dnsmasq` I set server=8.8.8.8, Google DNS): redirect is ok (ex: lolipop.fr => X.X.X.X)
3. **Unresolved Domain** : it does not work with domain, e.g. : http://stackexchange.com is *not* 'redirected' to X.X.X.X. (e.g.: whateverxlkjg.de => DNS UNRESOLVED ERROR)

Obviously, dnsmasq runs before iptables, and return solve error in step 2. Stopping the process...

**My question is:
How can I ensure IP, Solved domain *and* unsolved domain traffic redirection with iptables (I cannot/dontwant to use `dnsmasq`) ?**

I understand it is a tricky question... Please be indulgent.

Comment: How exactly are you redirecting all traffic to port 80? If `example.com` has a single `A` record, and traffic destined to that IP address is being redirected, then all "domain" traffic will be redirected.

Comment: Actually that s ok to me, all is redirected, IP and DOMAIN. But : the unresolved DOMAIN (ex: whatever5453512.fr is not resolved then not redirected). I ve editted my post.

Comment: With no DNS resolution, there is no IP address, and thus nothing for a firewall to act on. Thus, a DNS server must provide an IP address for any unresolved domains.